Maven Site Plugin - Code Syntax Highlighting
I am using the maven site plugin and MarkDown pages for my project documentation
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
            </plugin>


But this plugin does not provide a feature for code syntax highlighting like :
```java
int a =

The code syntax highlighting is a standard on this forum or on GitHub for markdown pages.
How can I add this feature to my Maven project too?

First I would recommend to use most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/ second the given syntax looks like markdown... which is in general supported ? Can you give an example project ? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html

I try to answer the question by myself.
As khmarbaise mentioned the latest maven plugin should be used.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1</version>
</plugin>

The highlight feature is not supported by maven site plugin at default. But you can make use of the highlightjs project. This is a JavaScript library that parses the HTML code for <pre> tags and applies a lot of style sheets to the code on the fly.
The only thing you need to use this, is adding the highlight.min.js and one of the themes .css files to your layout.
In case you use a site.vm template you highlightjs glue code should look like this:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    ....
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    @import url("$relativePath/highlight/default.css");
    </style>
    <script src="${relativePath}/highlight/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
   ...
  </head>

The highlightjs project provides a lot of different style sheets and you can test the layout on the Demo Page.
